# Proving existence and uniqueness of direct sum of representations of unital $C^*$-algebras

Tags: representation-theory, c-star-algebras, direct-sum

From Sunder's [*Functional Analysis: Spectral Theory*](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Esunder/fa.pdf), Exercise 3.4.3.

> Let $\{ \pi_i : A \to \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_i) \}_{i\in I}$ be an arbitrary family
> of representations of (an arbitrary unital $C^*$-algebra) $A$; show
> that there exists a unique (unital) representation $\pi : A \to \mathcal{L} (\mathcal{H})$,
> where $H = \oplus_{i \in I} \mathcal{H}_{i} $, such that $\pi(x) = \oplus_{i \in I} \pi_i(x)$. (See Exercise
> 2.5.8 for the deﬁnition of a direct sum of an arbitrary family of
> operators.) The representation $\pi$ is called the direct sum of the
> representations $\{ \pi_i : i \in I\}$, and we write $\pi = \oplus_{i \in I} \pi_i$. (Hint:
> Use Exercise 2.5.8 and Lemma 3.4.2.)

I do not understand what I am supposed to prove here and how. The exercise given in the hint says there is a unique operator in a direct sum of Hilbert spaces which behaves similarly to the representation given in this problem, I tried to prove this representation is an operator and get the unique operator from that, but I couldn't get anywhere. Also, I'm not certain how to use the lemma, it seems I might have to use it to prove that the norm of the representation matches the one of the operator in the previous exercise, but I also got stuck trying to prove that.

Comment: If $v=(v_i)_{i\in I}\in H$ then $\sum_{i\in I} \|v_i\|^2 <+\infty$.  Since $\|\pi_i(x)\|\le \|x\|$ for all $i\in I$, then $\|\pi_i(x)(v_i)\|\le\|x\|\|v_i\|$.  Since $\sum_{i\in I} \|x\|^2 \|v_i\|^2 <+\infty$, it follows that $\pi(x)v:=(\pi_i(x)v_i)_{i\in I}\in H$.  That's the representation.